# Improper integral existence exercise

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

$$\int _0^1\frac{\ln (1+\sqrt{x})}{\sin(x)} \, dx\:$$

So the singularity point is at $0$, so we`ll use this test: $$\lim _{x\to 0}\frac{\frac{\ln(1+\sqrt{x})}{\sin(x)}}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}}=\lim_{x\to \:0}\frac{\frac{\ln(1+\sqrt{x})}{\sin(x)}}{\frac{\sqrt{x}}{x}}=\lim_{x\to \:0}\frac{\ln(1+\sqrt{x})}{\sin(x)}\cdot \frac{x}{\sqrt{x}}=1$$
The last limit is calculated by L'Hopital's rule of $\lim_{x\to \:0}\frac{\ln(1+\sqrt{x})}{\sqrt{x}}$.

Therefore as $\int _0^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} \, dx<\infty$ exist so as $\lim_{x\to \:0}\frac{\ln(1+\sqrt{x})}{\sin(x)}<\infty $
Is it correct ?

Comment: The result is correct.  What is written at the very end is untrue (typo?).. Limits should be taken from the right only.

Comment: I guess you meant $\int_0^1 \frac{\log(1+\sqrt{x})}{\sin(x)}dx$ exists. Your answer is correct !

Comment: Oh, we use this symbolic structure: $<\infty$ to an improrer integral who's result is final (exists). Just like in seires.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The approach used by the OP is correct, but there is another approach that I thought would be instructive here.  We note that

$$\sin x=x+O(x^3)$$

and

$$\log (1+x)=x+O(x^2)\implies \log (1+\sqrt{x})=\sqrt{x}+O(x)$$

Then, we have

$$\frac{\log (1+\sqrt{x})}{\sin x}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}+O(\sqrt{x})$$

from which it is evident that the integral exists as an improper Riemann integral.